# jplayer is not working with shoutcast stream what i should do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

To play a SHOUTcast stream on my website I am using JPlayer . When playing normal MP3 files it shows the progress of a track: there is a green progress bar that shows how much of the current track has played, but with a SHOUTcast stream this does not work.

I have been doing some research and it seems impossible to make it work for streams:

here is mu source code:

Answer (score 0):

In a stream you can obtain the 'progress' of 'how long the stream has been playing'. Since it's a 'stream' and not an mp3 with a known duration, you can't show progress percentages in the same way as you would for an mp3.